# How to get the new available books from amazon using their Product API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-product-api

I am trying to use amazons product api to get a list of their new available books and I am having trouble doing it. I am currently using the ruby-aaws-0.8.1 gem that I found [here](http://www.jeffreyjason.com/2010/07/12/amazon-product-advertising-api-w-ruby/).

Right now I have set up code that gets me the newest book using a keyword and have set a date rank but currently the api is giving me back the newest book, but is there a way to have it so that it can give me the newest available book?

This is the first response I am getting back, but this book is currently not available. [http://www.amazon.com/Artificial-Intelligence-Programming-techniques-Basic/dp/B000YC4KT6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000YC4KT6)

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w

require 'amazon/aws/search'

include Amazon::AWS
include Amazon::AWS::Search

is = ItemSearch.new( 'Books', { 'Keywords' => 'Programming',
                              'Sort' => 'daterank',
                              'Available' => 'Available' })

is.response_group = ResponseGroup.new( 'Small' )

req = Request.new()
req.locale = 'us'
resp = req.search( is, 1 )

items = resp.item_search_response[0].items[0].item

items.each { |item| puts item, '' }

puts items.count
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't have privilege to comment. Not sure this is the issue, but I think the ItemSearch parameter to get only available products is "Availability" rather than "Available". You will also need to use this parameter in combination with a Merchant ID and Condition as per the doc (http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/2010-11-01/DG/ItemSearch.html). Could you please try changing:

```
is = ItemSearch.new( 'Books', {'Keywords' => 'Programming',
                              'Sort' => 'daterank',
                              'Available' => 'Available' })
```

with

```
is = ItemSearch.new( 'Books', { 'Keywords' => 'Programming',
                              'Sort' => 'daterank',
                              'Availability' => 'Available',
                              'MerchantId' => 'ATVPDKIKX0DER',
                              'Condition' => 'All'})
```

The MerchantId given above is Amazon's US MerchantId. You will need to change this MerchantId accordingly if you want to look at Amazon's inventory in other countries, or if you want to look at third party's (read non-Amazon) inventory.